# Error: unexpected '{' in. Using if...else statements

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, error-handling

I am practicing running loops with R and can't seem to get these if..else statements to work.

I have a matrix "vector_walk" with 1 column and 1 row with a value of 116. I am running an if...else statement to create a new row of values in a separate matrix called "grid_walk". Based on the value "vector_walk" has, "grid_walk" is supposed to create a new row with 1 of 8 possible combinations of 0 and 1. I realize this could probably be solved outside of if..else, but I want to stay inside because I am trying to learn. The code I have so far is:

```
vector_walk <- matrix(0, ncol = 1, nrow = 1) #DF to hold vector values
grid_walk <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

if(vector_walk>338&vector_walk<=22){
  grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(0,1))
  } else if(vector_walk>22&vector_walk<=68){
    grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(1,1))
  } else if(vector_walk>68&vector_walk<=112){
  grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(1,0))
  } else if(vector_walk>112&vector_walk<=158){  
  grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(1,-1)) 
  } else if(vector_walk>158&vector_walk<=202){
  grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(0,-1))
  } else if(vector_walk>202&vector_walk<=248){
    grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(-1,-1))
  } else if(vector_walk>248&vector_walk<=292){
    grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(-1,0))
  } else(vector_walk>292&vector_walk<=338){
    grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(-1,1))}
```

with error codes:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"    grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(-1,0))
  } else(vector_walk>292&vector_walk<=338){"
>     grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(-1,1))}
Error: unexpected '}' in "    grid_walk <- rbind(grid_walk, c(-1,1))}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `else` doesn't need a logical statement as `else` is to specify all the other cases

```
...
 else {
     rbind(grid_walk, c(-1, 1))
   }
```

It can be reproduced with a simple `if/else`

```
v1 <- 25
if(v1 > 24) print("hello") else(v1 < 25) print("not")
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "if(v1 > 24) print("hello") else(v1 < 25)
> print"

```
if(v1 > 24) print("hello") else print("not")
#[1] "hello"
```

NOTE: It may be better to do the assignment `grid_walk <-` once outside the nested `if/else` statements

---

Another option is to use `cut/findInterval` to create an index and use that to index to return the vector of values

```
ind <- as.integer(cut(vector_walk, 
   breaks = c(-Inf, 22, 68, 112, 158, 202, 248, 292, 338, Inf)))

f1 <- function(i1) {
        i1 <- deparse(substitute(i1))
        switch(i1, 
               `1` = c(0, 1),
               `2` = c(1, 1),
               `3` = c(1, 0),
               `4` = c(1, -1),
               `5` = c(0, -1),
               `6` = c(-1, -1),
               `7` = c(-1, 0),
                c(-1,1)
               )
  }
```